# Set value after return

Tags: c#, .net, return

I have this function:

```
public static IList<T> Reverse<T>(MyList<T> list)
{
    list.Reverse = true;
    return list;
}

public class MyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    public bool Reverse;
    ...
}
```

This function works well, but the list will remain reverse. I want to set  Reverse to false, after I return a reverse list.

I want to do somethin like:

```
public static IList<T> Reverse<T>(MyList<T> list)
{
    list.Reverse = true;
    return list;
    // Here I want to set Reverse to false.
    // list.Reverse = false;
}
```

For example using method:

```
Reverse<int>(Mylist)[1] 
// I want MyList.Reverse == false
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: It sounds very much like an XY problem. **Why** do you want to do this, what are you trying to achive with this? `return` means returning from the method. The method does not -- cannot do anything after it has returned to the caller of this method. You are pretty much asking something like "after i left my car and am back in my home, i want to be still in the car and drive it. How do i do it?"

Comment: @elgonzo To me, it sounds like the OP wants to return a new list instead of changing the original like `.Reverse()` does. Something similar to what linq does

Comment: What about using out keyword

Comment: `Reverse` seems to be a property that you have created (not a part of `IList<T>`. You need to display your definition of the `IList` property here

Comment: Probably @CamiloTerevinto is right. In this case, you could create a copy of list and set Reverse on the copy.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is that it is not possible to run code after return is called.
What you can do is.
 1. You can wrap your code in

```
try{
    //DoSomething 
    return Something
}
finally{
    //DoSomethingElse()
}
```

In this case DoSomethingElse will run.
2. To perform some operations after return you can use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`

```
public static IList<T> Reverse<T>(MyList<T> list)
{
    list.Reverse = true;
    //This will run after return when a thread pool thread becomes available
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate{ list.Reverse = false; });
    return list;
}
```

So more or less something that matches your expected behavior will be :

```
public static IList<T> Reverse<T>(MyList<T> list)
{
    try{   
        list.Reverse = true;
        return list;
    }
    finally{
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate{ list.Reverse = false; });
    }
}
```

If you want to achieve `Reverse<int>(Mylist)[1]`  without changing the Reverse property you need to create new list instance


More information about `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` Method you can find at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: This will change the returned list at an undefined time in the future which will probably be very unexpected for the caller.

Comment: Not in unexpected time but when the thread pool becomes available.
Well i have mentioned it in answer as you can see the line.
//This will run after return when a thread pool thread becomes available
You can propose some better way to achieve that?